# Login from database

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

based on this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/423233/How-to-Connect-to-MySQL-Using-Csharp

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE Employee {
ID int,
Name varchar(20),
Password varchar(20),
}
```

and now I have a new row

```
INSERT INTO employee(ID, Name, Password) VALUES (001, 'John', 'abc')
```

and here's how I try to receive the Password as a string from ID that is taken from TextBox

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=sad - final project; Uid=root; Pwd=");
        connection.Open();
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Password FROM  employee WHERE ID = '" + Input_ID + "'";
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);

            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(myDataSet);
        } catch blablabla
```

If Input_ID is 001, I expect to get a string from myDataSet that contains the password (which is "abc") so that I can compare it with password input from another textbox. How could I convert this myDataSet to String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `ExecuteScalar` instead:

```
var pwd = command.ExecuteScalar() as string;
```

and now you have the `string`. I'm not going to address the security concerns with your code in this answer, they are vast.

Comment: security is not a concern at this time so simpler execution is what I'm looking for. Thanks to you!

Comment: @Anggrian, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 0):

```
DataRow row = myDataSet.Tables[0].Row[0];
string password = row["Password"];
```

should get you the string.

Comment: `row["Password"]` cannot be implicitly converted to string.  You would need to add the `ToString()` method to that for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ExecuteScalar` to get the password to string.  Also you should use the `using` keyword to ensure proper disposal of your connection/command.  Also, you need to use parameters in your select to prevent injection.

```
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=sad - final project; Uid=root; Pwd=");
    using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT password FROM employee WHERE ID = @UserId", connection)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Input_ID); 

            var pwd = command.ExecuteScalar() as string;
            //Do something with the stored password.
            //Consider encryption and other security concerns when working with passwords.
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle your exceptions
        }
    }
```